# How do i convert this mysql query to a Rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, join, group-by

How do I convert this to a rails query? I can't seem to figure it out.

```
select * from (select * from users order by date desc) as sub group by environment_id, platform;
```

That's my mysql query that works and is what I need, but I'm having trouble converting it to a ruby on rails query. Here is what I have so far, but not having any luck:

```
 data = User.select("*").join("(select * from users order by date desc) as sub").group("environment_id, platform")
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm missing why you're using "as sub", but just in case it's not really needed, you could try this:

```
User.order(:date => :desc).group('environment_id, platform')
```

Comment: sub is the alias for the sub-table i am trying to query

Comment: You are asking for all the rows from one table twice, merging into once... Could you post a sample output from your working mysql query, just to see what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: nevermind, i figured it out. I just used the find_by_sql() funciton and it worked

Comment: @C- Could you post your answer please.

Comment: In general, you should learn not to use "find_by_sql"... It's potentially vulnerable to sql injections. And I'm still trying to figure why the use of a "sub-table" with no conditions whatsoever....